# Spark code to read property and define logger and multi threading

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, properties

Below is the code to run spark code in thread
we can run spark task on parallel below code is example to run using thread

spark dataframe pass query to run future will help to run parallel

Added logger file and property file to read property

```
package Test

import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.io.Source.fromFile

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object ParallerlExecution {
  val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    log.info("Start of program!!")
val queryList=loadFile()
    parallerlExecution(queryList)
log.info("End of program!!!")
  }

  def loadFile():List[String]={
    fromFile("").getLines().toList
  }

  def parallerlExecution(queryList:List[String]): Unit ={
    val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    /*
    --properties-file  parallelprop.conf
    
    create file and put info like below
    spark.jdbc.url <jdbc url >
    spark.jdbc.username <user name for db>
    spark.jdbc.password <password for db>

     */
    val url=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jdbc.url")
    val username=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jdbc.username")
    val password=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jdbc.password")

    val pool= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)

    for(query<-queryList){

      val r= new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {

          val st = System.currentTimeMillis();

          val df = spark.read
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
            .option("dbtable", query)
            .option("user", username)
            .option("password", password)
            .load()
          val count = df.count
          val et = System.currentTimeMillis();

          val resIntoHdfs=spark.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(url,count))
          resIntoHdfs.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs path to write result example /user/abc/"+et)
          val rddOfDataframe = df.rdd.map(_.toString())
          val size = calcRDDSize(rddOfDataframe)
          val logInput="Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  Record Count " + count + " StartTime " + st + " Endtime " + et +" Size: "+size+ " Query: " + query
          case class LogOut(value:String)
          import spark.implicits._
          val logDF=spark.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(LogOut(logInput))).toDF
          logDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").save("hdfs path to save result example /home/abc/logsqlresult")
          println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  Record Count " + count + " StartTime " + st + " Endtime " + et +" Size: "+size+ " Query: " + query)
log.info(logInput)
        }
      }
      pool.execute(r)


    }

    pool.shutdown()
  }
  def calcRDDSize(rdd: RDD[String]): Long = {
    rdd.map(_.getBytes("UTF-8").length.toLong)
      .reduce(_+_) //add the sizes together
  }
}
```

we can run spark in multi threading defined thread pool and in loop we can run our spark program in parallel mode

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test

import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.io.Source.fromFile
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputStream
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path



object ParallerlExecution {
  val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val hdfsFilePath=args(0)
    log.info("Start of program!!")
val queryList=load_file("")
    parallerlExecution(queryList,hdfsFilePath)
log.info("End of program!!!")
  }

 /* def loadFile():List[String]={
    fromFile("").getLines().toList
  }
*/

  def load_file(path:String)={
    val pt=new Path(path)
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    val br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)))
    var res:List[String]=  List()
    try {

      var line=br.readLine()
      while (line != null){
        System.out.println(line);

        res= res :+ line
        line=br.readLine()
      }
    } finally {
      // you should close out the BufferedReader
      br.close();
    }

    res
  }
  def parallerlExecution(queryList:List[String],hdfsFilePath:String): Unit ={
    val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    /*
    --properties-file  parallelprop.conf

    create file and put info like below
    spark.jdbc.url <jdbc url >
    spark.jdbc.username <user name for db>
    spark.jdbc.password <password for db>

     */

    /*val url=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jdbc.url")
    val username=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jdbc.username")
    val jecksProvider=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.jecks.provider")
    val passwordAlial=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.password.alias")*/

    val prop=readHdfsFile(hdfsFilePath)
    val jecksProvider=prop.getProperty("jeck-provider")
    val passwordAlial=prop.getProperty("password-alias")
    val url=prop.getProperty("url")
    val username=prop.getProperty("username")

    val password=extractPwdFromJceks(jecksProvider,passwordAlial)
    val pool= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)

    for(query<-queryList){

      val r= new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = {

          val st = System.currentTimeMillis();
          val tableName=""
          val df = spark.read
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
            .option("dbtable", query)
            .option("user", username)
            .option("password", password)
            .load()
          val count = df.count
          val et = System.currentTimeMillis();

          val resIntoHdfs=spark.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(url,count))
          resIntoHdfs.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs path to write result example /user/abc/"+et)
          val rddOfDataframe = df.rdd.map(_.toString())
          val size = calcRDDSize(rddOfDataframe)
          val logInput="Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  Record Count " + count + " StartTime " + st + " Endtime " + et +" Size: "+size+ " Query: " + query
          case class LogOut(value:String)
          import spark.implicits._
          case class Out(tableName:String,sizeOfData:String)
           df.write.mode("overwrite").save("<path hdfs>"+tableName)

          val sizeOfData=getFileSizeByPath("<path hdfs>"+tableName)

          val outDF=spark.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq(Out(tableName,sizeOfData.toString))).toDF

          outDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").csv("hdfs path to save result ")

          println("Thread" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  Record Count " + count + " StartTime " + st + " Endtime " + et +" Size: "+size+ " Query: " + query)
log.info(logInput)
        }
      }
      pool.execute(r)


    }

    pool.shutdown()
  }
  def calcRDDSize(rdd: RDD[String]): Long = {
    rdd.map(_.getBytes("UTF-8").length.toLong)
      .reduce(_+_) //add the sizes together
  }

  def extractPwdFromJceks(jceksfile:String, password_alias:String):String = {
    val conf:Configuration = new Configuration()
    conf.set(CredentialProviderFactory.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_PATH, jceksfile)

    conf.getPassword(password_alias).mkString("")

  }

  def readHdfsFile(path:String):Properties={
    val prop=new Properties()
    val fis=FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).open(new Path(path))
    prop.load(fis)
    prop

  }

  private def getFileSizeByPath(filePath : String): Long = {
    val path = new Path(filePath)
    val hdfs = path.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
    val cSummary = hdfs.getContentSummary(path)
    val length = cSummary.getLength
    length
  }


}
```